# Playwright:TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locator')

Tags: javascript, playwright

Trying to automate a browser application, the credentials of which gets populated in a window popup. Solution to handle could be achieved, but the issue now is, when executing multiple test, the above error is coming. Please find the main code

```
 const {test,page} = require('@playwright/test');
    const {MainPage} = require('../pageObjects/MainPage');
   

     const main_page = new MainPage(page);
    test.describe("Smoke Test",()=>{
    test("Open browser and login to the application",async()=>
    { 
    const login =main_page.getLoginPage();
    await login.initialiseBrowser();// Open the url and key in User Id and Password
    await login.navigateToApp();//Verify successful login into the application
    await login.navigateToProgram();//Verify if user can click on a program
    });
    test("Validate the side menu are available by clicking", async()=>
    {const side_menu = main_page.validateSideMenu();
    await side_menu.navigateToSideMenu();//Validate if the side menu is available and can be clicked
    });
    });
```

Comment: I don't see `locator`  anywhere in this code. Can you share the full stack trace and a [mcve]? Which line is the error on?

Comment: validateSideMenu() method is the method with returns the page.  I have created a class SideMenu, in which i have a method navigateToSideMenu(), under which the locator is residing. Instead of having multiple tests if i have a single one it works. The problem arises when one more test is added. Page instance is not being effectively passed is what i understand.

Comment: Thanks, but we're still missing a full stack trace and [mcve].